# Constant pointer reference

Tags: c++

For the code below:

```
class Foo {
 private:
    int var;
    int* var_ptr;

 public:
    Foo() : var_ptr(&var), var_ptr_ref(var_ptr) {}
    int*& var_ptr_ref;  // Read only access to var and var_ptr
};
```

Is it possible to make the pointer const and the actual variable constant when accessed via `var_ptr_ref`?

Answer (score 2):

Try declaring `var_ptr` as `const int` and `var_ptr_ref` as `const int * const &`:

```
class Foo {
 private:
    int var;
    const int * var_ptr;

 public:
    Foo() : var_ptr(&var), var_ptr_ref(var_ptr) {}
    const int * const & var_ptr_ref;
};
```

Comment: I get an error `binding reference member 'var_ptr_ref' to a temporary variable` for the constructor line.

Comment: @user1135541 At least my VS2015 is happy to compile it.

Comment: Its a warning, using clang.

Comment: @user1135541 Clang might be correct actually. Try the updated version.